# IntelliJ replacing $MODULE_DIR$ with physical path

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ & facing an issue.

In module properties under Path tab, I wanted my output path to be like "$MODULE_DIR$\bin" but when i am trying to check-in into my repository, its replacing "$MODULE_DIR$" with actual physical path. So if someone else will checkout that .iml file will have my module's physical path.

Did someone please confirm if this issue is resolved or it is still an issue?

IntelliJ IDEA version details is as below -

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.2 Build #IU-172.3757.52, built on August 15, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b10 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 7 6.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944614/intellij-checkstyle-setting-path-relative-to-the-module)

Comment: Try using a forward slash in your path, this should work.